# NGINX regexp at the end of location path

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to set up a `location` such that suffix `/reset_password/any_text` would load index.html from the directory specified in the `alias`. Unfortunately, with no luck...

```
#   location /reset_password {
#       alias /var/www/grades-ui;
#   }

    location /reset_password/([0-9a-z]*) {
        alias /var/www/grades-ui;
    }
```

The commented out code works fine to load exact path `/reset_password`, however my goal is to serve `/reset_password/any_text_or_number`.

Any ideas why my regular expression wouldn't work?
Or maybe I'm doing something else completely wrong?

**Edit: the complete conf file**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/grades-ui;
    server_name www.mygrades.co.uk mygrades.co.uk;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mygrades.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mygrades.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        index index.html;
        add_header X-debug-message "Location / reached" always;
    }

    location ^~ /reset_password/(.*)[a-z]/ {
        alias /var/www/grades-ui;
        add_header X-debug-message "Location /reset_password/$1 reached" always;
    }

    location ^~ /reset_password {
        alias /var/www/grades-ui;
        add_header X-debug-message "Location /reset_password reached" always;
    }

#    location /reset_password/([0-9a-z]*) {
#       root /var/www/grades-ui;
#       try_files /index.html =404;
#    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    if ($host = mygrades.co.uk) {
        return 301 $host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.mygrades.co.uk mygrades.co.uk;

#    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; # managed by Certbot

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: Try: `location /reset_password { root /var/www/grades-ui; try_files /index.html =404; }`

Comment: It actually worked because it loads correctly, but the url becomes e.g. `https://mygrades.co.uk/reset_password/test/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/`

Comment: Any ideas as to why this could be?

Comment: To add to this: it turns out my browser was simply caching the previous results and it actually works just fine! @RichardSmith if you were to post this as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing your `location` syntax. The *regular expression* `location` is introduced with the `~` or `~*` modifiers. The `^~` modifier means something else entirely. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The `location ^~ /reset_password { ... }` block already matches any URI that begins with `/reset_password`, including `/reset_password/foo`. You do not need a regular expression to match the trailing part of the URI.

You could use an `alias` directive with a *regular expression* `location`, but in that case, `alias` requires the entire pathname to be provided. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details. For example, this should work:

```
location ~* ^/reset_password {
    alias /var/www/grades-ui/index.html;
}
```

But the solution I would suggest is a prefix `location` with a `root` and `try_files` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details. For example:

```
location ^~ /reset_password {
    root /var/www/grades-ui;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ^~ string is a prefix location modifier which tells nginx to skip processing of regular expression locations if the prefix location is matched. A regular expression location uses just ~ or ~* to ignore case. Check the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more details.

That said, if you don't need to capture any regex pattern matches, just go with a simple prefix location. Regex locations are expensive and they interfere with the natural flow of  nginx. The author of nginx, Igor Sysoev, explains in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWRYbLKsS0I).

A good way to use a regex location is to wrap it in a prefix location. This isolates it from the rest of the configuration and makes it easier to debug. Your config will also scale more smoothly. Here's an example:

```
location /reset_password/ {
    location ~ /reset_password/([0-9a-z]*) {
        # ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have actually changed my code to use this method instead!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!